# Parallels Plesk API slow

Tags: php, performance, plesk

I have Plesk version 12.0.18 in use. I now want to create a new subdomain through a PHP page and the Plesk API. Once I call the page loads this for about 20 seconds and then gets a timeout. The GET requests via the API run fast, but the POST requests result in the timeout. The subdomain is still applied. So far I have not found a solution that worked.

Is this normal for Plesk or I can change that somewhere?

Greeting Timo

Comment: Could you please share api request body and brief plesk description like OS, total amount of domains, sub-domains and domain aliases?

Comment: @OlegNeumyvakin Once I had to install Plesk new, I have the problem still, but only the first time after a certain time. So I call the function that is the time-out and then if I still investing another subdomain with the function, it works and I get a response. Here is the request body: `<packet>
 <subdomain>
  <add>
   <parent>domain.de</parent>
   <name>ls</name>
   <property>
    <name>www_root</name>
    <value>/ls.domain.de</value>
   </property>
   <property>
    <name>php</name>
    <value>true</value>
   </property>
  </add>
 </subdomain>
</packet>`

Answer (score 0):

You can Increase the time to wait to restart Apache after a change via Settings -> Apache Webserver > Apache Restart interval. Set this now to 60 seconds. 
Plesk is doing a immediately restart after adding a new website.